# Can I enable PC to support GATT server (peripheral) role?

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt, bluetooth-gatt, bluetooth-peripheral

I tested `BluetoothAdapter adapter = await BluetoothAdapter.GetDefaultAsync();`

and found out that `IsPeripheralRoleSupported = false`.

I tested on both desktop and laptop, which are both Windows10(1903), but had no luck.

**Is there any way I can enable the PC to support peripheral role?**

Or is this property unable to be changed?

Comment: Yiu can but with very few Bluetooth Adapters. 100% working one is Laird BT851

Comment: Hi, thnx for the comment. I understand that it might not work, but can you please tell me how to enable it? I can at least try :)

Comment: You can not "enable" it. It depends only on hardware (Bluetooth module). Use compatible Bluetooth module (the one I posted above is compatible) and GATT server (peripheral mode) will work. Windows has very special requirements fro Bluetooth hardware to support peripheral mode and only few devices can be used.

Comment: ohhhhhh I see!!!! Thank you! I'll buy it and try it :)   I thought Larid BT851 is like the PC model name or so. Is this like a dongle? Currently I'm using CSR4.0 Dongle for desktop. I'm not really sure if I can replace this with Larid BT851 or I need to use both of them.

Comment: Its a dongle (https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/laird-wireless-thermal-systems/BT851/BT851-ND/8251358). You should replace your one with this. Or, if you have build-in dongle, disable build-in. There are also 2 more known and tested models but they are not USB.

Comment: @Jess Before buying new dongle, First check if your current dongle supports GATT peripheral role from product description or chip data sheet. Check whether your OS supports GATT peripheral role, You might have to install additional software or enable some configuration for this.

Comment: Oh right! I never thought about the case that the dongle already supports peripheral role but the PC does not. I will check if my OS supports it or not! Thank you so much for your help! :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike Petrichenko answered on the comment if anyone looking for the answer to this question!

> You can but with very few Bluetooth Adapters. 100% working one is Laird BT851

> You can not "enable" it. It depends only on hardware (Bluetooth module). Use compatible Bluetooth module (the one I posted above is compatible) and GATT server (peripheral mode) will work. Windows has very special requirements fro Bluetooth hardware to support peripheral mode and only few devices can be used.

> It's a dongle (https://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/laird-wireless-thermal-systems/BT851/BT851-ND/8251358). You should replace your one with this. Or, if you have build-in dongle, disable build-in. There are also 2 more known and tested models but they are not USB.